# SharePoint 2007 performance issues

Tags: performance, sharepoint

I don't expect a straightforward silver bullet answer to this, but what are the best practices for ensuring good performance for SharePoint 2007 sites?

We've a few sites for our intranet, and it generally is thought to run slow. There's plenty of memory and processor power in the servers, but the pages just don't 'snap' like you'd expect from a web site running on powerful servers.

We've done what we can to tweak setup, but is there anything we could be missing?

Comment: Can you provide some example of what specifically is slow?  Is it just in general or is it when performing certain actions?

Comment: I am not sure about akashic. From my experience it is slow overall even just for regular surfing through pages.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andrew Connell's latest book (Professional SharePoint 2007 Web Content Management Development) has an entire chapter dedicated to imporving performance of SharePoint sites.

Key topics it covers are Caching, Limiting page load (particularly how to remove CORE.js if it's not needed), working with Disposable objects and how to work with SharePoint querying.

2 really good tricks I've got are to use the CSS Freindly Control Adapters to generate smaller HTML for the common components (menus, etc) and setting up a server "wake up", so when IIS sleeps the app-pool due to inactivity you can reawaken it before someone hits your site.

Answer (score 4):

There is a known issue with initial requests once an IIS application pool has unloaded the SharePoint resources or recycled itself where the spin-up on a new request is very slow.

Details about why that happens and how to fix it can be found here; [SharePoint 2007 Quirks - Solving painfully slow spin-up times](http://jritmeijer.spaces.live.com/Blog/cns!8A48A27460FB898A!965.entry?wa=wsignin1.0)

Answer (score 2):

Microsoft has released a white paper on this very issue.

> How Microsoft IT Increases
>   Availability and Decreases Rendering
>   Time of SharePoint Sites  Technical
>   White Paper Published: September 2008

Download it [from here](http://download.microsoft.com/download/0/E/B/0EBA7263-A555-4279-B9DD-1720F0139A2E/SharePointOptimizationTWP.doc).

Answer (score 1):

SharePoint has a lot of limitations that contribute to low performance problems we may call them performance bottlenecks. The SharePoint performance problems occur primarily due to the following reasons:

- BLOBs overwhelm SQL Server
- Too many database trips for lists

You can dramatically improve SharePoint performance if you use a few of intelligent techniques which are:

- Externalize Documents (BLOBs)
- Cache Lists and BLOBs

Microsoft Office SharePoint Server (MOSS) is an extremely popular product that improves effectiveness of organizations through content management and enterprise search, shared business processes, and information-sharing across boundaries for better business insight. And StorageEdge is an extremely fine product that enhance/improve SharePoint performance.
By using StorageEdge SharePoint's performance can easily be enhanced.

Answer (score 0):

Just a few ideas...

Is displaying your pages as slow when doing it from the Server or from a Client? If slower from client, do check your network.

Are your pages very "heavy"? (means, many elements, web parts and so on?) Than maybe it's normal.

Have you noticed they load slowlier since you've add one specific web part? Maybe there's some issues with that specific web part (for example, it's accessing to a document library that has many -thousands of- documents). If that's the case, try to deactivate that specific web part and see if the performance works better.

Answer (score 0):

I noticed that Sharepoint loves to add a ton of JavaScript. If you run a Browser with slow JavaScript (say, Internet Explorer), i notice that it sometimes does not "feel" fast.

Also, if you are running custom code on it: Make sure to dispose your SPWebs after use, that can up a lot!

Answer (score 0):

Are you running on virtual or physical servers? We found that it is significantly faster on physical servers. Also, check the disk performance - if you are running the servers from a SAN it might be a sign that your SAN is over utilised.

Answer (score 0):

To investigate SharePoint performance issues, I would try these things first, in that order:

- Run SQL profiler for those non-performing pages. SharePoint API excels at hiding what's going on behind the scenes in respect to database roundtrips. There are single API calls that, without the knowledge of the developer, generate many roundtrips, which hurt performance.
- Profile w3wp.exe process serving your SharePoint site. That's going to tell you relative API usage. Focus on ticks, no time, and do a top-down inclusive time analysis to see which calls are taking up most of the time. See [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/teamsystem/aa718860.aspx) for instructions.
- Run Fiddler or Microsoft NetMon to spot potential excessive client roundtrips (i.e. between browser and web front end server) and redirections (301's).

Answer (score 0):

The three main major components of SharePoint setup is SharePoint Server (the one which runs WSS/SPS services),  SQL Server DB and IIS.

You said you have decent power for your SharePoint services and I assume IIS would definitely be on a good machine.

Usually SQL Server setup that hosts the SP related DBs that would slow down the page loads.  I would want you to take a look at your whole SQL Server related performance counters and you might want to tune these DBs too (which includes OS Server/Stored Procedures/Network, etc)

Hope this adds to your checklist of things you want to take a look at.